Two basic timers on an STM32 don't work simultaneously
I have an STM32L073RZ and it has TIM6,7 basic timers. I need a timer interrupt. TIM7 works fine as I want, but TIM6 doesn't. I tried different settings of prescaler and counter: same as TIM7, almost same, low values, high values, but nothing. The interrupt is always generated only by TIM7.
No matter if it is in debug or normally running, TIM6 never calls  the callback function. NVIC setting is activated as well. Tee base frequency is 2MHz, prescaler and counter of TIM 6 are 1000 and 20.

Please post full code so someone can try to read or run your code.

Several ideas: 1.) Copy paste errors. Verify you haven't copy/pasted something and forgot to adapt the 7s and 6es. 2) Have you enabled the clock for Timer 6? You can also close in the problem by looking at the TIM& Counter register. Does it count? If yes, the timer works and there is something with your interrupt. If not, your timer is the culprit.

I don't know a single thing about the STM32. How are the interrupt vectors arranged in memory? is there a different vector location assigned to TIM6 vs TIM7? How does the compiler parse syntax to associate a function with an interrupt vector? Please provide detailed examples.

@GNA OK, I forget declare for HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT for TIM6 but its still dont work sumltaneously. Like if i comment TIM7, then TIM6 works, but together they dont work

@sneiksus I guess you need to carefully read AN4776. That looks like the right source to me, anyway. If you fully understand that 70+ page paper, then I think you will be in fine shape.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In STM32Cube I created a project for the STM32L073RZT3. I activated tim6, In parameter settings I changed "Trigger event selection" to "Update event" and in "NVIC Settings" I enabled the global event.
Now the code line in the function MX_TIM7_Init changed from:
sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
to:
sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;.
What is the value for MasterOutputTrigger in your code?
